# Pandas DataFrame to Excel report using a template

Tags: python, excel, pandas, templates, dataframe

Is there a Python library that allows me to export a Pandas DataFrame to an "Excel report" using some sort of template to format the Excel file (conditionally colourise cells, customise fonts and colours of cells, insert empty lines, placement of data in cells, etc.)

I'd like to use this user-definable "template" together with a system-generated DataFrame as input to create an Excel report (which is not necessarily strictly tabular like a DataFrame). The intuition is that writing a template (perhaps in some domain-specific language?) would be easier and more restricted than "writing code" (for instance by using `xlsxwriter`). Apologies, but I have to admit that my prior research on this was short, partly due to a lack of keywords and success thereof.

Comment: An idea of exporting to an excel template, you will need to call python for the dataframe export and then VBA through python to copy and paste external data.

Comment: VBA would be considered “coding”. What I am looking for is something like Mako or Jinja (or Mustache) but just for Excel.

Comment: okay, those will work too. i have just read about Pycgettb  in python and it looks promising. Have a look.